# Selecting single values from pandas dataframe using lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

ind = [0, 1, 2]
cols = ['A','B','C']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape((3,3)),columns=cols)
```

Say you have a pandas dataframe `df` looking like:

```
    A  B  C
 0  0  1  2
 1  3  4  5
 2  6  7  8
```

If you want to capture a single element from each column in `cols` at a specific index `ind` the output should look like a series:

```
 A  0
 B  4
 C  8
```

What I've tried so far was:

```
 df.loc[ind,cols]
```

which gives the undesired output:

```
   A  B  C
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8
```

Any suggestions?

context:
The next step would be mapping the output of an `df.idxmax()` call of one dataframe onto another dataframe with the same column names and indexes, but I can likely figure that out if I know how to do the above mentioned transformation .

Comment: Can you clarify in this question. Are the values that you need to return always in the same order as the indices and columns? (i.e. you always want the diagonal values) or will order of the values in this `df.loc[ind,cols]` change?

Comment: What did you pass in for ind and cols that gave you that result? Obviously passing`ind` and `cols` just passes all the indexes and columns as you defined above, so why would you expect a singular value?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use [DataFrame.lookup()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html):

```
In [6]: pd.Series(df.lookup(df.index, df.columns), index=df.columns)
Out[6]:
A    0
B    4
C    8
dtype: int32
```

or:

```
In [14]: pd.Series(df.lookup(ind, cols), index=df.columns)
Out[14]:
A    0
B    4
C    8
dtype: int32
```

Explanation:

```
In [12]: df.lookup(df.index, df.columns)
Out[12]: array([0, 4, 8])
```

Comment: Er, wouldn't it just be `df.lookup(ind, cols)`?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, unfortunately not - there will be no index values...

Comment: This is definitely preferable over list comprehension

Comment: Well, I mean you'd still have to wrap it in `pd.Series`,but i mean instead of using `df.index` and `df.columns`, since I *think* the OP wants those to be arbitrary, i.e. `ind = [0, 1, 1]`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, ah, i've misunderstood you. Sure we can use: `df.lookup(ind, cols)` as you said

Answer (score 7):

Here's a vectorized one with NumPy's [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) to select one element per column, given the row indices `ind` per col -

```
pd.Series(df.values[ind, np.arange(len(ind))], df.columns)
```

Sample run -

```
In [107]: ind = [0, 2, 1] # different one than sample for variety
     ...: cols = ['A','B','C']
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(9).reshape((3,3)),columns=cols)
     ...: 

In [109]: df
Out[109]: 
   A  B  C
0  0  1  2
1  3  4  5
2  6  7  8

In [110]: pd.Series(df.values[ind, np.arange(len(ind))], df.columns)
Out[110]: 
A    0
B    7
C    5
dtype: int64
```

**Runtime test**

Let's compare the propose one against the pandas built-in vectorized `lookup` method proposed in @MaxU's solution and since we are seeing how good the vectorized ones are, let's have greater number of cols -

```
In [111]: ncols = 10000
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,(100,ncols)))
     ...: ind = np.random.randint(0,100,(ncols)).tolist()
     ...: 

# @MaxU's solution
In [112]: %timeit pd.Series(df.lookup(ind, df.columns), index=df.columns)
1000 loops, best of 3: 718 µs per loop

# Proposed in this post    
In [113]: %timeit pd.Series(df.values[ind, np.arange(len(ind))], df.columns)
1000 loops, best of 3: 410 µs per loop

In [114]: ncols = 100000
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,9,(100,ncols)))
     ...: ind = np.random.randint(0,100,(ncols)).tolist()
     ...: 

# @MaxU's solution
In [115]: %timeit pd.Series(df.lookup(ind, df.columns), index=df.columns)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.83 ms per loop

# Proposed in this post
In [116]: %timeit pd.Series(df.values[ind, np.arange(len(ind))], df.columns)
100 loops, best of 3: 5.76 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another way using mutiIndex, if you like using `.loc`

```
df1=df.reset_index().melt('index').set_index(['index','variable'])
df1.loc[list(zip(df.index,df.columns))]
Out[118]: 
                value
index variable       
0     A             0
1     B             4
2     C             8
```

Answer (score 1):

You could zip the column and index values you would like to retrieve the values for and then create a series from that:

```
pd.Series([df.loc[id_, col] for id_, col in zip(ind, cols)], df.columns)
A    0
B    4
C    8
```

Or if you always just need the diagonal value:

```
pd.Series(np.diag(df), df.columns)
```

Will be much faster

Answer (score 1):

There should be a more direct way but this is what I could think of,

```
val = [df.iloc[i,i] for i in df.index]
pd.Series(val, index = df.columns)

A    0
B    4
C    8
dtype: int64
```